# Visual Studio won't let me step into my own code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I've got an issue with "step into" in VisualStudio debugger.

Here is piece of my code

```
        if (eventHandler.onStep() != STATUS_OK)
        {
            ANativeActivity_finish (application->activity);
        }
```

when debugger hits

```
        if (eventHandler.onStep() != STATUS_OK)
```

string, I would like to step into my function `eventHandler.onStep()` which contains

```
status Game::onStep ()
{
    return renderer->update ();
}
```

But VisualStudio is just ignore it and pass by.

I'm already unchecked "Enable just my code" and "Step over properties and operator (Managed only)" but still no luck. How do I figure this out?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `onStep` that work ?

Comment: What about setting a breakpoint at the if clause and then press F11?

Comment: This might be connected to compiler optimizations, inlining, actually

Comment: **Jerome** No. 

 **oLen** That exactly what I do. And there is no help, VS just ignore it, like there is nowhere to go.

 **Joker** there is no inlining